# How to invoke shell and pass arguments to spiders

Tags: scrapy

I was used to do that in order to inspect a HTML and find out xpaths:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.domain.com/whatever
```

Now I have a spider which must receive some arguments. Something like

```
$ scrapy crawl -a arg1=one MySpiderForDomainDotCom
```

And I still want to invoke the shell from command line. But now scrapy try to use/load my spider (documentation says it do it in this way) and I get an error saying the spider have no arguments.
My question is how to invoke shell from command line when the spider must receive arguments?

I have tried some things and combinations, searched the web, but nothing...

PS: scrapy 0.22.2

PS2: I do not want to invoke the shell from within my spider.

Comment: Have a look at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#scrapy-shell . You can invoke the shell within your spider callback, and you can use `scrapy crawl -a arg1=one MySpiderForDomainDotCom` to invoke it

Comment: I know. I do not want to invoke the shell from my spider. It is painful. It's like measuring the temperature. I do not want to build a weather station only to measure the temperature. Just as I do not want to run the spider (that do a lot of things!) just to find out some xpaths.

Comment: `scrapy shell` can take a `--spider` argument but unfortunately the spider creation is not passed any additional arguments, contrary to `scrapy crawl` for example. You can probably do that by calling `crawler.spiders.create(spidername, **args)`

Comment: Ja, this confirms it is not possible to do what I want...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to simply invoke:

```
$ scrapy shell
```

from the command line, and once console is launched:

```
>>> fetch('http://www.domain.com/whatever')
```

The scrapy shell command will load all the settings you have defined defined in settings.py. This does not initiate any spider.